# Salvar 2 valores en un select laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo mi siguiente select que muestra la lista de clientes de una tabla:

```
<label>Asignar nuevo cliente
        <select name="idCliente" class="form-control input-sm">
         @foreach($Clientes as $ClientesAs)

<option value="{{ $ClientesAs->idCliente}}">{{ $ClientesAs->nombre}}</option>

         @endforeach  
        </select> 
    </label>
```

Mi intencion es guardar el idCliente en una tabla clientes_contactos, al selecionar el cliente y submith, me guarde el id selecionado y quiero guardar el nombre del cliente {{ $ClientesAs->nombre}} perteneciante a lo selecionado igual mente

Mi controlador es:

```
public function contactosStoreCliente(Request $request)
{
$validatedData = $request->validate([    
     'idCliente'=> 'required|max:255',
 ]);   
 $Clientes_contactos=Clientes_contactos::create($validatedData);
 return redirect('/contactos'); 
}
```

Comment: Consulta, ¿es realmente necesario guardar el nombre del cliente si ya estas guardando el id de este, para poder luego hacer una consulta entre esas tablas mediante un join?

Comment: si, en realidad estoy anidando un if en la tabla, (perro esto es otra historia). me seria muchio mas facil guardar el nombre y mostrarlo ya que se guardo el cliente que se asigno al contacto en la tabla de "clientes_contactos" para futuras consulta :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es que creo que si tienes una base de datos relacional y en una tabla tienes una llave foranea de otra tabla, no hace falta guardar mas que el `id` de la otra tabla para poder llegar a consultar los valores de esa.

Aún asi, lo que yo haría sería lo siguiente, suponiendo que envias los datos del formulario y el que importa es el campo `idCliente`

Controlador

```
public function contactosStoreCliente(Request $request)
{
  $clienteID = $request->get('clienteID')
  $cliente = Cliente::find($clienteID); // obtengo el registro del cliente para poder   obtener el nombre de este.
  // Guardo un nuevo registros
  $Clientes_contactos = new Clientes_contactos([
           'clienteID' => $clienteID, // id del cliente obtenido del formulario
           'nombreCliente' => $cliente->nombre // nombre del cliente de la tabla cliente
        ]);
}
```

Tendrías que agregar el modelo de `Cliente` a tu controlador.

Comment: no pude responder ayer por tiempo pero me fue muy util gracias :)